# How to operate on POST requests received from the front end?

Tags: reactjs, express, frontend, backend

I am new to fullstack development. I am trying to create a fullstack calculator, for learning purposes. My frontend is made using React and my backend is made using Express. I am not saving any data; Hence, I am not using any DBMS. In the frontend, the user can form a mathematical expression and onclick of an 'equal button' a post request containing the expression is sent to my server.
My question is after I send a post request to the server, how do I mathematically operate on the request's body and calculate the answer to the expression and send the answer as a get request?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need a backend to calculate, just take values from the input and do it in a function, return result, and render.

Comment: Yes, a calculator app doesn't need a backend. I actually used calculator as a simple example to explain what I wanted to do. In my real project, I have some algorithms that are going to perform calculations of higher order. I don't know if it's appropriate for the client side to have this functionality, that's why I am looking for doing this in the backend. Perhaps, I need to create an API for it?

Comment: @Jam3sHalliday has point. It doesn't look like you need a server/backend for what you described. However, if you want to perform the calculations on the backend you only need to create one POST request and not a POST and GET. Your POST request body should contain the relevant inputs that you can then plug into a function and the results of that function will be sent back to the client in the response.
example `return res.status(201).json(someCalculation)`